# Using regular expression to extract content of file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, grep

I have a link and I would like to return only content between www. and .com

e.g `www.blablabla.com` would return only `blablabla`

How could I do that? When I use `grep '\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]*\.`' it gives me `.blablabla.`

Comment: `awk -F. '{print $2}'`

Comment: Yes it would work but i forgot to mention that i do not want to use cut or awk to cut it with delimiter `.`

Comment: _"i do not want to use cut or awk to cut it with delimiter `.`"_  Apparently, you don't want `grep -P` either.  To get the best answer, you should explain your requirements.  There are many good solutions to this problem.  You should explain why you are rejecting the best ones.

Comment: Homework problem?

Answer (score 22):

```
$ echo "www.blablabla.com" | grep -oP '(?<=\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]*(?=\.)' 
blablabla
```

`-o` -- print only matched parts of matching line

`-P` -- Use Perl regex

`(?<=\.)` -- after a literal `.`, aka, a "positive look-behind" ...

`[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]*` -- match zero or more instances of lower & upper case characters, numbers 0-9, literal `.` and hyphen ...

`(?=\.)` -- followed by a literal `.`, aka a "positive look-ahead"

See this [link for more on look arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Tools like https://regex101.com/ can help you break down your regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks that's what i wanted but what does it do ? Could u explain it a bit more please? Also `-P` uses Perl regular expression is there any way to do it just with grep regular expressions?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: If you don't want to use `-P` there is no way you can do this using grep re alone. If you want to stick with `grep` consider using `tr` to drop the `.` like this `echo 'www.blablabla.com' | grep -o '\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]*\.' | tr -d .`

Answer (score 2):

**sed** solution:

```
$ str='Hellowww.hello.comMywww.world.comWorld'

$ echo "$str" | sed -e 's/com/com\n/g' | sed -ne '/.*www\.\(.*\)\.com.*/{ s//\1/p }'
hello
world
```